# Teamcity artifacts path not found

Tags: teamcity

I have a project in TeamCity with the following build settings regarding Artifact Paths:

```
artifacts => artifacts
3rdPartyDlls => 3rdPartyDlls
```

However, when I build the project, I get the following warning:

```
[12:40:46]Publishing artifacts (1s)
[12:40:46][Publishing artifacts] Collecting files to publish: [artifacts => artifacts, 3rdPartyDlls => 3rdPartyDlls]
[12:40:46][Publishing artifacts] Artifacts path 'artifacts' not found
[12:40:46][Publishing artifacts] Publishing 42 files using [WebPublisher]: 3rdPartyDlls => 3rdPartyDlls
[12:40:46][Publishing artifacts] Publishing 42 files using [ArtifactsCachePublisher]: 3rdPartyDlls => 3rdPartyDlls
```

Now, I've checked in the working directory of the TeamCity Build Agent, and there is both a "3rdPartyDlls" and an "artifacts" directory, side by side in the same folder´.

I don't understand how TeamCity can find the "3rdPartyDlls" but not the "artifacts" folder, even though they are both right there.

Can somebody please help me with this?

Thanks in advance,
Kira Resari

Comment: Try to modify the path like :    %system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir%/artifacts and see if it works